# sys.exit doesn't terminate the code under test

Tags: python

I'm writing a test for a piece of python code that exits in a certain condition:

```
def work(self, args, parsed_args):
    if util.key_exists():
        existing_key = util.read_file(filepath)
        if existing_key == parsed_args.key:
            print(ERROR_MESSAGE)
            sys.exit(1)
        elif not prompt(WARNING_MESSAGE.format(existing_key)):
            return
    util.work(parsed_args.key)
```

This is the test I'm writing:

```
@patch('sys.exit')
@patch('util.read_file')
@patch('util.key_exists')
def test_work(self, mock_key_exists, mock_read_file, mock_sys_exit):
    args = ['command', 'some_key']
    mock_key_exists.return_value = True
    mock_read_file.return_value = 'some_key'
    with patch('sys.stdout', new=StringIO()) as fakeOutput:
        somecode.main(args)
        self.assertEqual(fakeOutput.getvalue().strip(), ERROR_MESSAGE)
        assert 'exit' in repr(mock_sys_exit)
```

The test fails, because after running `sys.exit(1)` it continues the process and calls `util.work`. If I put a `return` statement after `sys.exit(1)` the test passes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the 1 do in sys.exit(1)?  I would have just used sys.exit() - another option might be os_.exit()

Comment: Try quit() or sys.exit(0).